# how to query a post based on previous page post ID

Tags: php

sorry I probably didn't word the question properly. So i'll describe what im trying to achieve.

I have Page A that has a slider of the different posts. When you click on one it redirects you to the full article(Page B) which also has the same slider. Page B where the full article is has the "next" and "prev" buttons to cycle through the other available posts. For example there are #10 posts in Page A slider, #5 is chosen so this should redirect to the full article of #5 on Page B. And this is where my issues lie.

The slider and query for both page A and B is like this:

```
<?php 
    $args = array (
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'blog'
    );
    $blog_list = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php if( $blog_list->have_posts() ):?>
<?php while( $blog_list->have_posts() ) : $blog_list->the_post();?>

<li class="column swiper-slide">
    <div>
        <?php echo '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'">'; ?>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();
```

I believe It is a query issue because the URL bar of page B displays the correct link but page B article shows #1 but it should show #5. How should i adjust the query? or if someone could let me know what part of the wordpress doc i should be reading up that would be great as im actually new to this.

Comment: By "when first directed it should be directed to the chosen post" you mean that, when the page is first displayed, the slider (on that page) should have its initial position corresponding to the page -- sort of a "you are here" indicator. Correct? Anyway, looks like you're using a plugin to create the actual slider, right? Questions about customizing it are off-topic here. (As an aside, you could use the html5 range slider.)

Comment: Page A has a slider with #10 link posts. Say you choose link #5 then u should be directed to page B with the full article of #5 but instead of that happening, page B shows #1. I thought it would be the query issue as im using the same code above for page B. In the url, it is article #5 but because of the current query it just starts at #1. So i just don't know how to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Where did you paste this code, to `single.php`, `content.php`, somewhere else? Any changes related to the main query?

Comment: the code is in the page itself. single-blog.php